# Creating a new user doesn't include features of cmd?

Tags: 12.04

I created a new user using the following command:

```
sudo useradd -m jkeesh
sudo passwd jkeesh
```

Everything is working fine. I can able to log in and to do other stuffs. But in the command line, I'm missing the ability and features of real Ubuntu. What I mean is , when I tried to move to end of the command using my direction keys, I get this:

```
^[[A^[[A^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[B^[[C
```

And there is no auto completion. Hitting the `tab` key doesn't help.

Where I'm making the mistake?

I'm very new to Ubuntu, I need some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the default shell is `bin/sh`.

You should do this. Edit `/etc/passwd` and check for the line that has `jkeesh` as username. You will see something like :

```
jkeesh:x:1005:1005::/home/jkeesh:/bin/sh
```

Change the line to `bin/sh` to `bin/bash`.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: [Supplementary link to SU](http://superuser.com/a/459984/104400)

Answer (score 0):

You created the new user using the `useradd` command, which provides the new user a default sh shell. You could have used it this way -  `useradd -d /home/user -s /bin/bash -G group -m user` (remove the -g in case you don't want him to be in a specific group) to get the bash shell.

But since you have created the user anyways, we need to change the shell to bash, and then you will have all the features you want.

On your Terminal, do `chsh`. Enter the sudo password, and enter `/bin/bash` and *enter*. This should get you going. I guess you will need to do a system restart.

**edit**: Prefer the `adduser` utility over `useradd`

Answer (score 0):

You say you are new to Ubuntu, then maybe you would be better using System Settings > User Accounts  to add new users. System Settings is available by clicking on the gear wheel icon at the top right of the screen.